# Should instant yeast be room temperature when used?

Tags: yeast

Should instant yeast be at room temperature when used to make bread? I store mine in the freezer but I was wondering if it should be allowed to warm up a little before use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It probably doesn't matter too much.  By the time you mix it with other ingredients, and then add the friction of kneading it will be the temperature of other ingredients.  I keep mine in the refrigerator and just pull it out and add it to the mix.

Comment: I also keep it in the fridge, and have never had a problem… but don’t leave it out of the fridge for extended periods or you risk condensation

Comment: I buy yeast by the pound (I make about 5 loaves of bread a week).  I use a no-kneed recipe that takes a 1/4 teaspoon of yeast per loaf - so the yeast lasts a _long_ time.  I keep the bulk of the yeast in a sealed thermos bottle in the fridge, occasionally transferring it to a 113g Fleishman's jar for daily use (filling the jar about 2/3).  Each day, I pull out the little jar, add my yeast and put it back in the fridge.  It works like a charm, whether with at the start of a new bag of yeast or as I'm finishing it up.